# Nginx redirect to URL

Tags: nginx, redirect

Using my Nginx install I was forwarding my requests to www.example.com:8080/twinkle/index.jsp

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host www.example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/twinkle/;
}
```

I am deploying another application that is going to primarily be used to download and running on port 81

www.example.com:81/blacksheep/mary/mary.wav
www.example.com:81/blacksheep/tom/tom.wav

```
location /blacksheep/(.*) {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:81/media/(.*) ;
     }
```

However this takes me back to www.example.com/twinkle/blacksheep/xxxxx

Not sure what I am missing.. (I am an amateur in this space, filling up temporarily )

thanks.

Comment: keep in mind, proxy_pass isn't the same as rewrite

Comment: Your location is erroneous

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following after Anatoly's comment & it worked.

```
location /blacksheep {
     rewrite ^(/blacksheep)(.*)$  /blacksheep$2 break;
     proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
}
```